# PHP arrays validation

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a form that gets validated when submit. I make sure some fields are not empty, date fields have a valid format, etc. I have a block of check boxes with a text input next to it.

```
Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="jobBonusId[]" value="1"  />
Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="jobBonusId[]" value="2"  />
Option 3
<input type="checkbox" name="jobBonusId[]" value="3"  />

Amount 1
<input type="number" name="jobBonusAmount[]" step="0.01" value="0.00" />
Amount 2
<input type="number" name="jobBonusAmount[]" step="0.01" value="0.00" />
Amount 3
<input type="number" name="jobBonusAmount[]" step="0.01" value="0.00" />
```

So, if any of the jobBonusId[] checkbox gets checked it creates an array. Now, I want to validate the jobBonusAmount[] if its -parent- checkbox was checked and make sure is not empty or equals 0.00.

So far, I have the following code:

```
// Run the script
if (isset($_POST['addJobRecord']) && $_POST['addJobRecord']=='oTzm50xfm') {
   // Validate date format
   if (!validateDate($jobDateStart) || !empty($jobDateEnd) && !validateDate($jobDateEnd)) {
      // Show the form
      $displayContent = $displayForm;
   // Validate data dates
   } else if ($jobTimeIn>$jobTimeOut) {
      // Show the form
      $displayContent = $displayForm;
   // Validate bonus values
   } else if (!empty($jobBonusId) && is_array($jobBonusId)) {
      // At least one jobBonusId checkbox was checked
      // Make sure its child input is not empty

      ... HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK ...

   } else {
      // Everything looks good
      // Add record to database
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Thank you much!

Comment: if you create the associative array on front end, send that array through a hidden field and validate `jobBonusAmount` for each `jobBonusId` that will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array key, and check child by `jobBonusId` key:

```
foreach ($jobBonusId as $key => $bonusId) {
    if (!empty($bonusId)) {
        if (!empty($jobBonusAmount[$key])) { // check a child
            // if child is filled
        } else {
            // not filled
        }
    }
}
```

It means, that `$jobBonusId` array is the same to `$jobBonusAmount` array

Comment: I already tried that, but don't know how to exit the parent else if (!empty($jobBonusId) && is_array($jobBonusId)). Look: // Start errors count
   $err = 0;
   // Loop trhu array values
   foreach ($jobBonusId as $id=>$val) {
      // Validate bonus amount
      if ($jobBonusAmount[$id]=='0.00') {
         // Add count
         $err++;
      }
    }
    // Validate errors found
    if (!empty($err)) {
       // Show the form
       $displayContent = $displayForm;
    }

Comment: @CarlosCharles if one of the cild if filled, use `break`. Also you can set flag (variable)  before foreach, and in case at least one filled - set flag to true